# Issue while executing commands on server B from Server A

Tags: shell, unix

I have a shell script which I need to execute from server A which executes commands in Server B as well. But I can execute those commands only being a root user in server B.

Manually if I login to server B then I have to change the user to root and execute delete commands. To automate this I am trying to write a script and execute from server A, but it asks me for password. How do I add my password in the script? (Though it is not recommended), or please suggest if any other way to tackle this.

Comment: Is `sudo` an option?  If so, it is likely to be the weapon of choice on Server B, if not Server A too.

Comment: You should copy the public key of the user that will run the script on server A and add to authorized_keys to root user on server B and disable password authentication. Assuming you have permit_root_login password-only in /etc/ssh/sshd_cofnig.

Answer (score 0):

Add your username in /etc/sudoers with nopasswd to remove password prompt

```
$ visudo
user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sshpass command with -p option

```
sshpass -p 'your_password' ssh root@your_host ls
```

refer manual of [sshpass](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass) for more options